# How to use functions in grunt-sass?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, node-sass

My current project uses grunt-sass to translate scss files into css.
According to the grunt-sass documentation, I can use any option that node-sass provides except for a few:

> Options
>
> See the node-sass options, except for file, outFile, success, error.

My project compiles two CSS files out of one SCSS file. The SCSS file has if-statements in it that provides different code depending on the value of the version variable ($bootstrap-version: 3; or $bootstrap-version: 4;).

I would like to use the node-sass option `functions` to return the bootstrap version to my SCSS files.

Here's my gruntfile. The `functions: {...}` path is how I would have expected the option to work.

```js
// Compile Sass
sass: {
bootstrap3: {
    options: {
      style: 'expanded'
      functions: {getBootstrapVersion: function(){return 3;}}
    },
    files: {
      'dist/bootstrap3/css/my-bs3-variation.css': './bootstrap3/scss/my-bs3-variation.scss'
    },
},
bootstrap4: {
    options: {
      style: 'expanded',
      functions: {getBootstrapVersion: function(){return 4;}}
    },
    files: {
      'dist/bootstrap4/css/my-bs4-variation.css': './bootstrap4/scss/my-bs4-variation.scss'
    }
}
```

In the SCSS file, I call the function like this:

```css
$bootstrap-version: getBootstrapVersion();

h1:before {
    content: "Bootstrap " + $bootstrap-version + " Version of ";
}
```

However, when trying to compile it, I get the errir `>> Error: error in C function getBootstrapVersion: A SassValue object was expected.` for the line where I call the function.

The example in the node-sass documentation does not help me much. What did I do wrongly? Or are there any better examples out there that I just did not find?

I use grunt-sass version 2.0.0 and node-sass version 4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions must return a `SassValue` object.

Unfortunately, I don't believe it is possible to do that with `grunt-sass` alone because we need to wrap your returned numbers `4` and `3` in typing functions defined in `node-sass` (which `grunt-sass` does not expose...).

For example, with **node-sass** in **javascript**, one may use something like `sass.types.Number(4)` to declare `4` as a Number `SassValue`.

Here, `sass` is the node-sass import `const sass = require('node-sass');`, which is not available in grunt...

Comment: Thank you miir, knowing that it is not possible in grunt-sass does already help a lot! 
grunt-sass might need to update the Options part in their docu though. I'll try to contact them.